# How to get minimum unused number from a column in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

In my database I have a table with column that indicates the code of each record ( aside from ID column ). this field is unique and each time the user tries to insert a record into the table, the first unused code should be assigned to the record. Now the table has the column of codes with the following order :

```
+------+
code
+------+
1
+------+
2
+------+
3
+------+
5
+------+
```

I want a query to return 4 as the result.
Note that this query is highly frequent in my system and the best query with minimum execution time will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is using a self-join acceptable? If so:

```
-- your test data:
WITH data AS (SELECT 1 AS code FROM DUAL
              UNION SELECT 2 FROM DUAL
              UNION SELECT 3 FROM DUAL
              UNION SELECT 5 FROM DUAL)
-- request:
SELECT COALESCE(MIN(d1.code+1),1) 
  FROM data d1 LEFT JOIN data d2 ON d1.code+1 = d2.code 
  WHERE d2.code IS NULL;
```

This will build the list of `data.code` without a successor. And using `MIN(...+1)`  you will get the first empty slot. I used `COALESCE(...)`  in order to handle the specific case where there isn't any entry in the data table.

And alternate form using a sequence generator *might* lead to better performances as is does not require the whole table to be traversed in order to perform the aggregate function `MIN()`:

```
-- your test data:
WITH data AS (SELECT 1 AS code FROM DUAL
              UNION SELECT 5 FROM DUAL
              UNION SELECT 2 FROM DUAL
              UNION SELECT 3 FROM DUAL)

-- request:
SELECT T.code FROM (SELECT d1.code
  FROM (SELECT LEVEL code FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL < 9999) d1 LEFT JOIN data d2
  ON d1.code = d2.code
  WHERE d2.code IS NULL
  ORDER BY d1.code ASC
) T WHERE ROWNUM < 2
```

The drawback is you now have an upper limit hard-coded. It might be dynamically inferred from the data table though. So is is not really blocking. I let you compare timings yourself.

---

> this field is unique and each time the user tries to insert a record into the table, the first unused code should be assigned to the record

Please note however this will lead to a race condition if two concurrent sessions try to insert a row at the same time. Given your example, they will both try to insert a row with `code = 4` -- obviously both will not succeed in doing so as your column is unique...

Comment: This query works for every entries, except for the case that we dont have 1 in code column.

Answer (score 1):

I recently use the code below:

```
SELECT t1.id+1
FROM table t1
 LEFT OUTER JOIN table t2 ON (t1.id + 1 = t2.id)
WHERE t2.id IS NULL
/* and rownum = 1 Need to use a sub select if you want this to work */
ORDER BY t1.id;
```

I run it every time that I need to insert a new row and use the minimum unused **id**.

I hope it works for your purposes.

Answer (score 0):

```
select level unusedval from dual connect by level < 10
minus
select tno from t2);
```

you can change level condition dependents on max value.